# Integrate a library inside a silverlight custom user control

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have made a user-control in a silverlight project that I want to distribute and include in other projects just by referencing a single dll file. But the user-control uses Windows Phone  Toolkit and to use the control in any project, one has to include its dll as well as the toolkit dll. Is there any way I could package them inside a single package for distribution?

I did my research and even downloaded some books. No solution so far.

I'm not a native English speaker so excuse my sentence structure please.

Answer (score 0):

[ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630) allows you to fuse two DLLs in one. I'm not sure it's compatible with Windows Phone, but it's worth a try. But it's a convenient tool only for internal use. I would firmly discourage using it for distributing a package to third-party developers, as it would cause dependencies issues. Let's say I'm using a newer version of the toolkit and I want to use your control, then my version of the toolkit will conflict with the one packaged.

Overall, there is no silver bullet. You can make a Nuget package, which will automatically add the necessary dependencies. But that's probably overkill for what you're trying to do. In most cases, manually adding a reference to the toolkit is the easiest way.

Comment: What if I can include the single control that I want from the source code of toolkit. Would that work?

Comment: @Arsalan00 It is, but depending on how the toolkit is made, you may end up including a whole bunch of classes. And updating your control to include the future fixes released in the toolkit will be a real pain. Still, if you want to go that way, don't forget to change the namespace of the toolkit classes, and mark them internal, to avoid any conflict if the programmer using your control is also referencing the toolkit.